# npm WARN Deprecated when installing ionic/cordova

Tags: node.js, cordova, npm, ionic-framework, installation

[Warning Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xf5I4.png)

I got this warning (image link above) when I installed cordova and ionic. I'm new to this and don't know what this means and if there is something I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to worry since it is a warning, not an error.

The *npmconf* package is now part of the npm version you are using. When you install ionic or cordova, its `package.json` file still has a reference to npmconf. Npm ignores it.